# Communication between FPGA and Aria V HPS?

Tags: c, fpga, intel-fpga, nios, qsys

I want to make communication using Altera MM Mailbox IP component, between Aria V hps and my nios processors.

[Project in Qsys](https://i.stack.imgur.com/O2Zg8.png)

I managed to write down C code for Nios processors (FPGA side) to work with mailbox IP, then I made header file for HPS using sopc-create-header-files via EDS.

[LINK TO GENERATED HEADER FILE](https://pastebin.com/hqdTNRZf)

This what sopc-create-header-files made for me:

```
#define MAILBOX_SIMPLE_0_COMPONENT_TYPE altera_avalon_mailbox_simple
#define MAILBOX_SIMPLE_0_COMPONENT_NAME mailbox_simple_0
#define MAILBOX_SIMPLE_0_BASE 0x60
#define MAILBOX_SIMPLE_0_SPAN 16
#define MAILBOX_SIMPLE_0_END 0x6f
```

But i don't know how to use it. In NIOS IDE i have included library  altera_avalon_mailbox_simple.h, and in DS-5 i don't have one. Is there any other mailbox librarys i should include in my DS-5 project?
Maybe i should map mailboxes as peripherals using same methodology?

```
void mmap_fpga_peripherals()
{
    h2f_lw_axi_master = mmap(NULL, h2f_lw_axi_master_span, PROT_READ | PROT_WRITE, MAP_SHARED, fd_dev_mem, h2f_lw_axi_master_ofst);

    if(h2f_lw_axi_master == MAP_FAILED)
    {
        printf("ERROR: h2f_lw_axi_master mmap() failed.\n");
        printf("    errno = %s\n", strerror(errno));
        close(fd_dev_mem);
        exit(EXIT_FAILURE);
    }

    fpga_buttons = h2f_lw_axi_master + BUTTONS_0_BASE;
    fpga_hex_displays[0] = h2f_lw_axi_master + HEX_0_BASE;
    fpga_hex_displays[1] = h2f_lw_axi_master + HEX_1_BASE;
    fpga_hex_displays[2] = h2f_lw_axi_master + HEX_2_BASE;
    fpga_hex_displays[3] = h2f_lw_axi_master + HEX_3_BASE;
    fpga_hex_displays[4] = h2f_lw_axi_master + HEX_4_BASE;
    fpga_hex_displays[5] = h2f_lw_axi_master + HEX_5_BASE;
}
```

But I don't think I should use `mmap_fpga_peripherals()` to map mailboxes. I'm not sure.

Comment: Maybe you would want to ask at one of Intel's [FPGA communities](https://community.intel.com/t5/FPGAs-and-Programmable-Solutions/ct-p/fpgas-programmable-devices).

Comment: I will this question there also. Thank you for feedback.

Answer (score 0):

You should also generate device tree binary by sopc2dts which is usually under path intelFPGA/xxx/embedded/host_tools/altera/device_tree. Then write Linux drivers on basis of the mailbox device. For detailed information please refer to specs in Linux project.

```
Documentation/devicetree/bindings/mailbox/altera-mailbox.txt
Documentation/mailbox.txt
drivers/mailbox/mailbox.c
drivers/mailbox/mailbox-altera.c
drivers/mailbox/mailbox-test.c
include/linux/mailbox_client.h
include/linux/mailbox_controller.h
```